# I have trouble going to the next page

Tags: flutter, dart

The first page is the page for entering the country code with the phone number, and when you press next, the next page does not appear. Verifying the number means that you enter the code that will reach your phone
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUx98.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and the error message as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think your verification is a return in future and before checking your name and country code you can't jump to next page. After chiking function use the funtion and navigate in then function.

Like this:
await checkDetails().then((value) {
});

Comment: Can I contact you on Instagram?

Comment: username: sahilatahar

Comment: I just sent you a message and asked to follow on Instagram

Comment: @Rabee Khaled Sheikh Ibrahim
 - Sidebar communications on Instagram defeat the purpose of Stack Overflow.  If you resolved the problem, please tell us how, and either "accept" this response or post your own solution.